# how can i pass request object from one class to another

Tags: java, web-services, servlets

I have the following code in Webservice.java:

```
String userId = strUserID;
entity.setUserTerminal(requestBean.getChannel());
entity.setUserId(userId);
entity.setLoginPwd(requestBean.getPassword());
entity.setLoginID(requestBean.getLoginId());
String strEntityId = (String) authenticationHash.get("16");
entity.setEntityId(strEntityId);
request.setAttribute("langID", requestBean.getLangId());
WEBSERVICE_LOGGER.debug(logPrefix+"entity obj ::{} " + entity.toString());
request.setAttribute("entity", entity);
```

I am not able to get this  request.setAttribute("entity", entity); in another action file I am getting null when hitting request.getAttribute("entity");

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the line- **request.getAttribute("entity");** gets executed BEFORE the response is served, because request parameters are nullified immediately after the response is served.. And that may be the reason that you are getting a null value.

Comment: Still I am getting null.